# Angular JS Change Class on ng-mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

Am trying to add a class (blue) to a button when ever you hover the button using AngularJS.

HTML

```
<button class="btn-add-optimize" ng-mouseover="hover(iets)">Add and Optimize</button>
```

AngularJS

```
$scope.hover = function (iets) {
    var Dit = this;
    Dit.add("blue");
};
```

Anyone can help me out? Preferable a small example, it would be very appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use css? .btn-add-optimize:hover {color: blue;}

Comment: I would highly advise using css, as well. Using angular for such functionality is going way over the top.

Comment: Thank you Blue, I end up using your solution :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I've used something like this with success:

```
<button
    ng-class="{'some-class':hovering}"
    ng-mouseenter="hovering=true"
    ng-mouseleave="hovering=false">Add and Optimize</button>
```

Entering and leaving the button toggles `$scope.hovering`, and the application of `some-class` is contingent on the `$scope.hovering` scope variable being `true`.

Comment: Using the CSS :hover pseudo-attribute should work for most cases, but if you want to use it to trigger other behaviors on the page as well, this will work nicely.

Comment: I had to write a directive for it, in my case i was doing it basically on all card likes elements wich was repetitive. https://github.com/guilhermegeek/pi-angular-class-hover

Answer (score 14):

```
<button
ng-class="{'some-class':hovering}"
ng-mouseenter="hovering=true"
ng-mouseleave="hovering=false">Add and Optimize</button>
```

You should use this form : **ng-class**

Comment: can't understand why people gave you 9 up votes when you just used the very same answer above you.

Comment: @msqar At the time, Ercan's answer was technically correct and Collin's contained a bug, even though it was otherwise correct and identical. Feel free to review [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12755495) to solve said bug.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 8, this works for me:

```
<nav id="sidebar" [class]="!hovered ? 'active': ''" (mouseenter)='hovered=true' (mouseleave)="hovered=false">
```